# LinearLayout: TextViews at left, big ImageView at right

Tags: android, layout

i'm working on a LinearLayout but unfortunately it's not working as it should.
The goal is to have a LinearLayout with two TextViews (one placed below the other) on the left side, and an ImageView on the right side.

The ImageView should be as big as possible, the TextViews should take the remaining space.

At the moment my layout XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_linearlayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="1dp"
android:background="@drawable/background" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/layout1label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="1234"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/layout2label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1234_label2"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
</LinearLayout>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/layout_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

The part that isn't working: If the text in the TextViews is "too long", the ImageView gets shrinked. I want it exactly the other way round.

Any solutions?

Comment: You should set the the attribute "android:layout_weight" to your linear layout and  your image view. So you can decide how much space each of one of this can have.

Comment: Tried this, but this also doesn't work.

Comment: try set weight in linearlayout to 8 and in imageview to 1. And see the difference, then increase the value of the linear layout if u want it to be smaller.

Comment: The problem is following: If i set a layout weight to the 2 elements, this layout weight defines a ratio of how to split the space between the elements. But i only need this ratio, if the imageview is too big.

Comment: So if i set a ratio by using those layout_weight attribute, it always takes this ratio, also if there would be enough space to make for example the 1st textview wider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be more efficient to use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`.  Then you can place your views without having to nest layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    />
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

By arranging the `TextView`s to be relative to the `ImageView` instead of the other way around, the `ImageView` takes priority for the space, and the text works with the remainder.

Comment: This solution seems to be nice, but there is one weakness: If the text of the title is too long, the imageview disappears. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
this might be help to you

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/layout1label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="1234"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/layout2label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1234_labj hairu iue rel2"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/layout_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, hmm isn't working for me, the image stays at a certain size and doesn't get as big as it would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

A little modification to Kirans Code..worked for me

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/layout1label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Name: BalaVishnu"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/layout_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/edit_icon" />
</LinearLayout>
```